TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object [line: 2, function: , file: dist/helpers]
i am creating an appscript add-on  using typescript and i did use tsc to compiles TypeScript code into JavaScript and clasp push to push it into the appscript editor but i am getting this error
ypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
this is the typescript function
export function buildComposeCard(subject: string, sender: string, body: string): GoogleAppsScript.Card_Service.Card {
  subject = subject || 'No Subject';
  sender = sender || 'Unknown Sender';
  body = body ? body.trim() : 'No content available';

  const draftButton = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Generate Draft')
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
          .setFunctionName('composeAction')); // Adjusted here

  const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Compose Email'))
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
          .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Compose your email here.'))
          .addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setTopLabel('Subject').setContent(subject))
          .addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setTopLabel('From').setContent(sender))
          .addWidget(draftButton)
          .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(body)))
      .build();

  return card;
}


after i push it to the appsscript editor i get this function this is the @ dist/helpers.gs:2 where i get the error "TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object
(anonymous) @ dist/helpers.gs:2"
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.buildComposeCard = void 0;
function buildComposeCard(subject, sender, body) {
    subject = subject || 'No Subject';
    sender = sender || 'Unknown Sender';
    body = body ? body.trim() : 'No content available';
    const draftButton = CardService.newTextButton()
        .setText('Generate Draft')
        .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('composeAction')); // Adjusted here
    const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle('Compose Email'))
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText('Compose your email here.'))
        .addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setTopLabel('Subject').setContent(subject))
        .addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue().setTopLabel('From').setContent(sender))
        .addWidget(draftButton)
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(body)))
        .build();
    return card;
}
exports.buildComposeCard = buildComposeCard;



which give me the error when i run it on the appsscript
i tried updating the dependencies still not working
